# Autocomplete Form Not Placing Cities into form?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been messing with googles API and am confused as to why places like Staten Island, Brooklyn, Queens and various other cities are not placed into the form where other cities are?
According to googles API, "locality" is the id to use to place the city and even running their code on JSFiddle its not working for some cities. Is this a glitch or are some cities not classified as "locality"?

Here is a link to the google api. From there you can open their code in JSFiddle.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "Brooklyn", "Queens", "Staten Island", etc are sublocalities, not: "city"/"locality":

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeD.html?address=brooklyn,%20ny

> sublocality:  Brooklyn

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeD.html?address=Queens,%20ny

> sublocality:  Queens

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeD.html?address=Staten%20Island,%20ny

> sublocality:  Staten Island

Comment: Also it is confusing as to why they would not make Queens a city(locality):? Is there any reason as to why it would be a sublocality?

Comment: That you would have to ask Google.  The tend to use data as the get it though.

Comment: Locality - "A locality is a fairly large portion of a city that has an official name. A locality can consist of several housing colonies/developments. Cities in some parts of the world may not have official localities."
Sub-locality/Neighbourhood - "A sub-locality or neighborhood is a smaller section of a city."

none of this is adding up... lol